# How to change Foreign Keys on a Join Table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I have the following tables.

```
class Reward ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :earned_rewards
  has_many :players, :through => :earned_rewards
end

class EarnedReward < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reward
  belongs_to :player
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :earned_rewards
  has_many :rewards, :through => :earned_rewards
end
```

My problem is that the Foreign Keys on the EarnedReward table are of type string, and don't conform to Rails conventions.  I want to add Integer fields (player_id, and reward_id) to the EarnedReward table to act as the new Foreign Keys, while keeping the old fields and their values.

I'm using Rails 4.1.1 and I'm not sure exactly how to accomplish this.

Comment: what's the current foreign keys ?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the current foreign keys have the default name, then create a migration to rename the old fields then create new ones

```
class DoBlaBla < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :earn_rewards do |t|
      t.rename :player_id, :old_player_id
      t.rename :reward_id, :old_reward_id
      t.integer :player_id
      t.integer :reward_id
    end
  end
end
```

I think this should do it, try it on a test db first.